# Sending a SAML assertion from IDP to SP

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

When the user is viewing the SP and he clicks the "Login" button, a popup pointing to the IDP's login form is opened. After the user provides their username/password and submits the login form within the popup, assuming the credentials are valid, how can I get the SAML assertion generated by the IDP back to the SP. Can I use window.postMessage?

Answer (score 1):

The response (including the SAML assertion) of the IDP will be send to the `Assertion Consumer Service URL` of your SP. At this point you can do everything you want with it and assuming the SAML assertion is correct, create an authenticated login session at the SP level.

Depending on your use case you could now exit the popup and refresh (maybe partially) the parent window so it will pick up the logged in user. You could use the [windows.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.opener) object to call a function on the parent window. The main use of `window.postMessage` is to send data between window/frames across domains. But because your a receiving the response on a SP URL you should not need this.

Based on your story I am wondering if your are doing an SP initiated SSO by sending an [AuthnRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0#Authentication_Request_Protocol) to the IDP?

Comment: "The response (including the SAML assertion) of the IDP will go to the Assertion Consumer Service URL of your SP." What do you mean by "will go"? That was essentially my question.

Comment: Also the popup window (located on the IDP) will be on a different domain than the SP. This software will be distributed freely so SP's are not trusted sites. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: When you are using SAML with the Web Browser SSO Profile your SP should provide an Assertion Consumer Service URL. This URL must be known by the IDP by exchanging metadata. In other words you should register the SP with the IDP. If that's not possible I am not sure if SAML can help you.

Comment: @user2390523 Changed will go into will be send.

Comment: I will have a list of registered API keys paired with URL's, from this I can build a list of Assertion Consumer Service URL's. Do you think that will work?

Comment: @user2390523: from my position...don't know because I don't know what your are talking about. I think you should take one step back and decide if SAML works in your use case. Try to understand the basics first.

Comment: Anyway I can contact you? Twitter perhaps? @tlovett12

Comment: Yes you can, I just followed you. Send me a DM