# How can I get SAML2 response and subject in assertion generated by IDP in SP controller end point?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, saml-2.0

We are going to use IDP initiated SSO for our service. Our IDP client is going to send us(SP) email Id as saml_subject in assertion along with other SMAL2 elements, I have following questions,

1. In what format SAML response will be received by SP service (Controller end point)
2. Then, how to retrieve email ID from saml_subject.

**Our stack :** We use asp .net(4.5) MVC, C#, we will be using [this](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2) SMAL2 Sustainsys library

This is what I have tried so for:

1. Question close to what I'm asking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473675/sending-a-saml-assertion-from-idp-to-sp) but did not get my answer.
2. Also tried writing end point which will accept XML reponse, and I sent dummy IDP request from https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/, changed 'Assertion Consumer Service URL' here to my end point, but samlResponse in this case received was null
   `[HttpPost]
   public ActionResult SamlTest(Xml samlResponse) {
    }`
3. Also, tried to accept stringResponse in end point, and then tried to convert it to XML but it failed to do conversion saying max length of the response can be ~160
   `[HttpPost]
   public ActionResult SamlTest(string samlResponse) {
    }`

Any help or guidence will be helpfull here.

Note :By using this library and by following [this](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/blob/940644de50fa981caa31f5e5d6e8c8a1dea401bc/Sustainsys.Saml2.Mvc/Saml2Controller.cs#L69) I was able validate the request successfully. But could not retrieve the IDP information.